# header location on PHP is not functioning

Tags: php, redirect, header

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Header Location + Content Disposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458854/header-location-content-disposition)

I have a page that generates excel report using  `header content-type` and save the generation information on the database (e.g. who generated the report,when etc.) My problem is why I can't redirect the page. below is the sample code/algo

```
// excel content
/* excel content populates here */

// output to excel file
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$positionFileName);
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");

// save logs on the database  
/* save logs code executed here */

// redirect page to get the logs on the database that display on the web page
header("location: report.php");  *<--- I can't redirect to report.php*
```

Here is exactly what I want

the user will do is to select type of report then click button generate to output the excel report (open/save dialog). then after that, the system will going to save the logs of generated report on the database then show it on the page. that's why I want to redirect it again on report.php so that the logs will be get again on the database to display on browser.

Comment: Silly question, perhaps, but have you tried to change `location` to `Location`? Also, if the page is just white, it might be WSOD.

Comment: What do you get ? Any error message ? What do you mean by "I can't" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The headers are colliding. First you say *"here comes a document"*, using `Content-Disposition: attachment`, and then you say *"Oh no, it's not coming, do an additional request to XYZ"*, using the `Location` header. You can omit the `Content-` headers to achieve the same result.

This however works for me:

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=foo.dat");
header("location: foo.dat");
```

In that I get redirected to the foo.dat file, which is displayed in the browser (so the `Content`-headers are ignored, since after the `Location`-header a new request is issued which does **not** get the `Content`-headers in its response. If you want to enforce `attachment`, either [configure your web server to emit those headers](https://serverfault.com/questions/101948/how-to-send-content-disposition-headers-in-apache-for-files) for certain extensions or directories, or use `fpassthru($filename)` without the `Location`-header to directly emit the file without running into memory errors:

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$positionFileName);
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");

// save logs on the database  
/* save logs code executed here */

fpasstrhu($positionFileName);
```

But please note that any output generated during the executing of the code after the first three `header()`statements will be outputted to the browser, which'll think it is file data.

I guess this is currently also happening, causing the `header("location: ...")` to fail. [Enable error reporting to see why and where there was data printed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/warning-headers-already-sent-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because you're telling the browser that it should expect an Excel file. THEN, after you've told the browser that it should expect an Excel file, you're attempting to redirect to another page. The problem lies in your approach.

Comment: Sorry I'm novice on PHP. So what is the best approach for that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? i.e. What does the user actually do when they are using this part of your application?

Comment: the user will do is to select type of report then click button generate to output the excel report (open/save dialog). then after that the system will going to save the logs of the generated report on the database then show it on the page after.

Comment: what's why I want to redirect to the report.php so that the logs saved on the database will be get again to display it on browser

Comment: Why not read the file, interpret it and then store the results in your DB before redirecting? How are you logging it to DB? Are you logging the entire output to DB?

Comment: e.g i have button generate report on the upper portion of browser then below that is the logs of generated report. after generating the reports, the logs below will be refresh

Comment: I'm just logging the report type and the user generates the report on the database. I'm not logging the actual report/file on the database.

Comment: Why not log the report type that the user has selected and then redirect?

Answer (score -1):

Check that you have not already output anything to the browser.

'location' should be 'Location' usually too.

Answer (score -1):

Edit This
   header("Location: report.php");

Comment: any reason for negative vote ??

Answer (score -1):

```
header( "Location: http://" . strip_tags( $_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST'] ) . "/report.php" );
```

Try this..  I always call the HTTP Host checker, to make sure I stay on the same domain.

**edit**: my bad, i learned it as writting it with a capital letter L ... sorry for the earlier note.

Comment: _"and yes, you have to type it with a capital L"_ - no you don't: [RFC 2616, section 4.2, Message Headers](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.2): _"Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. **Field names are case-insensitive**"_. There used to be browsers that assumed/required Capitalized-Header-Fields, but those are silly and should not have to be supported.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup. I was taught wrong then, @CodeCaster